# Remove lines containing 3 or more same characters in a row

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

I would like to remove all of the lines containing 3 or more same characters in a row.

INPUT:

```
colaZAAA
colaZBBB
colaZAAB
```

OUTPUT

```
colaZAAB
```

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Are the 3 occurrences consecutive or not?  What must be the result for `AbAcAd`?

Answer (score 0):

Here, we would be most likely adding two backrefereces to find those with repeating three chars, with an expression such as:

```
.+(.)\1\1
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/AvCa3T/1/)

#### Test

```js
const regex = /.+(.)\1\1/gm;
const str = `colaZAAA
colaZBBB
CCCcolaZBBB
colaZAAB`;
const subst = ``;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]